# Dynamically display current year in assembly info

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to set current year in AssemblyInfo file?

I used

Instead of this:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright 2012, Company Name.")>
```

tried this:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ", Company Name.")>
```

I get invalid constant error.

I don't want to use registry key entries, what is the optimum way of doing this? (so that when a  user right clicks on EXE & looks for assembly information can see current year).

Thanks.

Comment: Add a calendar alert to Outlook or whatever you use for Jan 1 each year to go and change all of your copyright dates in your application. :)

Comment: The Copyright statement is a constant that is built into the generated executable's file info. Do you expect Windows to run a function in your program every time it tries to get the copyright?

Comment: Do you wont a current year or year when build happen?

Answer (score 29):

I saw something on another post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/827209/857307) that could really be helpful here.

Try this.

Add a new file to your source repository somewhere common to all of the projects in your solution. Call the file something like AssemblyCopyright.tt

In the file, add the following code for c#

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © CompanyName <#=DateTime.Now.Year#>")]
```

or vb

```
<#@ template language="VB" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" #>
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection

<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © CompanyName <#=DateTime.Now.Year#>")>
```

Then, remove the AssemblyCopyright attribute from each of your AssemblyInfo.cs files.

Finally, add a link to the AssemblyCopyright.tt file to each of your projects.

The template file will recreate a new AssemblyCopyright.cs file on every build with the correct year.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy')), Company Name.")>
```

I haven't tried this exactly.  Since i define some other parts of the assembly info via the .csproj using a `WriteCodeFragment` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45248069/209568), I do it this way too - I define properties

```
  <!-- We started in 2021.  So, if it's still 2021 we just want to show '2021' -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy')) == '2021'">
    <CopyrightYears>2021</CopyrightYears>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- But for later years we want a range.  E.g. in 2023 it will show '2021 - 2023' -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy')) != '2021'">
    <CopyrightYears>2021 - $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy'))</CopyrightYears>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then, within the task that updates the assembly info i have an `ItemGroup` including

```
<AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyCopyright">
  <_Parameter1>"Copyright © $(CopyrightYears) ..."</_Parameter1>
</AssemblyAttributes>
```

The after the `ItemGroup` I have the following within that task

```
    <MakeDir Directories="$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
    <WriteCodeFragment Language="C#"
                         OutputFile="$(IntermediateOutputPath)Version.cs"
                         AssemblyAttributes="@(AssemblyAttributes)" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)Version.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

The functions you can use as properties are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019)

Comment: This solution also works for the new SDK-style csproj with automatically generated AssemblyInfo. Just add `<Copyright>Copyright $([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString('yyyy')), Company Name</Copyright>` in the first `PropertyGroup` of the project file.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way is to integrate this into your build process using tools like [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) or [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).

Here is an article that explains how to change your AssemblyInfo using MSBuild: 
Updating [Assemblies with A Version Number](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2010/12/07/simple-msbuild-configuration-updating-assemblies-with-a-version-number.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use NANT/MSBuild tasks to modify the AssemblyInfo.cs file like we do to change the Version of each assembly for every build.

For more information, visit http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

Answer (score 1):

Typically, for that kind of substitution, you use a pre-build step that invokes a script that automatically generates your assemblyInfo.cs file.

You can have a look at this thread : [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar question, but for new style csproj file; that contains the file version info. I found a great answer here [How to define current system date in post build event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484523/how-to-define-current-system-date-in-post-build-event). Oddly, that is about a question that is somewhat different than my and the OP question. But, I think the accepted answer to that is what I want. Namely, $([System.DateTime]::Now.Year) in the csproj files evaluates to the current year.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using a prebuild task. Should work on windows and unix. Will work with dotnet (if you run `dotnet build`, before `dotnet run`).

Add this to .csproj

```xml
  <!-- update assembly info -->
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Condition="$(OS) == Windows_NT" Command="set TargetDir=$(TargetDir)&#xD;&#xA;..\scripts\updateAssemblyInfo.cmd" />
    <Exec Condition="'$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))' OR '$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))'" Command="export TargetDir=$(TargetDir)&#xD;&#xA;bash ../scripts/updateAssemblyInfo.sh" />
  </Target>
```

AssemblyInfo.base.txt

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("Copyright © 2009 - <#=DateTime.Now.Year#> COMPANYNAME. All rights reserved.")]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("xxx")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
// [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

in **scripts** folder
updateAssemblyInfo.cmd

```
for /f %%i in ('"powershell (Get-Date).ToString(\"yyyy\")"') do set currentYear=%%i
echo %currentYear%
powershell -Command "(gc 'AssemblyInfo.base.txt' -encoding "UTF8") -replace '<#=DateTime.Now.Year#>', '%currentYear%' | Out-File -encoding "UTF8" 'AssemblyInfo.cs'"
```

updateAssemblyInfo.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
year=$(date +%Y)
echo "Current Year : $year"
contents=$(cat AssemblyInfo.base.txt)
# echo $contents
echo $contents | awk -v yr=$year '{gsub("<#=DateTime.Now.Year#>",yr); print}' > AssemblyInfo.cs
```