# How to define current system date in post build event

Tags: msbuild

I want to copy .dlls into a target directory of format "test\Project_yyyy.mm.dd"
Where yyyy - cuurent year, mm - current month, dd - current date.
When I give the below command in my post build event, I am getting an error.

```
xcopy /Y "$(TargetDir)*.*" test\Project_$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)
```

I could not find any macro which define current date. Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: I have reffered to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx where in I got some useful information. But I want this to be working even if I deploy it in a build server

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [MSBuild Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) to call some of the .Net API. You can use System.DateTime.Now to obtain current time, then fetch year/month/day as properties of this object.

Here is a code that does this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CurrentYear>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Year)</CurrentYear>
    <CurrentMonth>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Month)</CurrentMonth>
    <CurrentDay>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Day)</CurrentDay>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Print">
    <Message Text="Year: $(CurrentYear)" />
    <Message Text="Month: $(CurrentMonth)" />
    <Message Text="Day: $(CurrentDay)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me.  I was able to call Now.ToString("your_format") for more complicated formats.