# Run C# text template every build

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Last year I implemented this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314275/1166898 to automatically update the copyright notice when the project is built, but I found out this year that the template isn't run unless it's changed, and it warns me that it's not trusted before running it.

[image]

How do I

1. run this file every build without it needing to be changed
2. trust just this file without automatically trusting every other `.tt` file

If it's not possible, what's a better way of updating the copyright year automatically?

Answer (score 0):

There's a surprisingly easy way using [Property Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022) in your .csproj;

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <Copyright>My Company $([System.DateTime]::Now.Year)</Copyright>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So long as you haven't set `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`, then the usual set of assembly attributes will be generated for you from MSBuild properties. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#assembly-attribute-properties) for more info.