How to configure csproject so that "Add as Link" only in release mode but not in debug?
I'm talking about csproject in VS 2022, targeted to .Net framework 4.8
Is there anyway to configure the debug and release mode settings  differently? More specifically, I want to include a *.tt file into the csproject only during the release mode, but not in debug mode. In other words, the following setting in the csproject
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\AssemblyCopyright.tt">
      <Link>Properties\AssemblyCopyright.tt</Link>
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>AssemblyCopyright.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

Should be activated only during when I compile for debug, and not for release.
Motivation:
I want to dynamically generate the copyright notice based on current year, and so I use the code template generation way to do it. But the compilation process becomes slow. So I only want to dynamically generate the copyright notice during release mode when I do builds for my users, and not when I'm debugging and testing my software.
Edit:
It seems that the suggestion (<ItemGroup  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">) from the answer and the comment doesn't work. I wrote a very simple program with the following csproj content, and yet the copyright notice is still generated, in both DEBUG and RELEASE mode.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{333D8793-BFF2-47E0-902D-FA2BC8D797C0}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>WithoutCopyExe</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WithoutCopyExe</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyCopyright.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AssemblyCopyright.tt</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{508349B6-6B84-4DF5-91F0-309BEEBAD82D}" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <Content Include="Properties\AssemblyCopyright.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>AssemblyCopyright.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>

the tt file
<#@ template language="C#" #>
// Generate copyright dynamically. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314275

using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Hurray @ <#=DateTime.Now.Year#>")]

Here's my AssemblyInfo.cs; note that there is no Copyright defined
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("CopyrightNotice")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("CopyrightNotice")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("d6e52005-9be0-4571-b3fc-37c36c8c963b")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]



I'm not 100% sure, so I'll post this as a comment rather than an answer, but you may be able to add the following attribute to that ItemGroup or Content element: Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'".

Any of these elements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2022#supported-elements can have a condition.

@jmcilhinney, no it didn't work. See the updated question

As jmcilhinney said, you could try to use the Condition attribute of the Content element to specify when the item should be included. Here's how you can modify your csproj file to include the *.tt file only in the Release configuration:

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
  <Content Include="..\AssemblyCopyright.tt">
    <Link>Properties\AssemblyCopyright.tt</Link>
    <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>AssemblyCopyright.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>


With this configuration, the AssemblyCopyright.tt file will only be included in the project when the build configuration is set to Release.
Update:
I tested the code and steps, AssemblyCopyright.tt does not exist in Debug mode, it is added in Release mode. But when I checked the project file again, two ItemGroups were missing.
modify your .csproj file:

    <!-- <Compile Include="AssemblyCopyright.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>AssemblyCopyright.tt</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>-->


<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyCopyright.cs">
        <DependentUpon>AssemblyCopyright.tt</DependentUpon>
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <Content Include="Properties\AssemblyCopyright.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>AssemblyCopyright.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

Test steps:
Open your project in Visual Studio.
Navigate to the Solution Explorer.
Right-click on the .tt file (e.g., AssemblyCopyright.tt).
Select "Exclude from Project" to remove it from the project
temporarily.
1.Build your project in Debug mode:
Go to the "Build" menu.
Select "Build Solution".
After the build completes, ensure that there are no errors related to missing files or unresolved references.
Check the Solution Explorer to verify that the .tt file is not included in the project.
2.Now, switch your project configuration to Release mode:
Go to the Visual Studio toolbar.
Select "Release".
3.Build your project again:
Go to the "Build" menu.
Select "Build Solution" mode.
After the build completes, ensure that there are no errors.
Check the Solution Explorer to verify that the .tt file is included in the project under the Properties folder.
You can also inspect the contents of the bin\Debug and bin\Release folders to confirm that the AssemblyCopyright.cs file is generated only in the bin\Release folder.
If you need to delete AssemblyCopyright.tt when changing back to debug mode, you may need to add the Target.
These Target maybe helps.
<!-- Remove the .tt file from the project during Debug builds -->
<Target Name="RemoveTTFile" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Properties\AssemblyCopyright.tt" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<!-- Add the .tt file back to the project during Release builds -->
<Target Name="AddTTFile" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Properties\AssemblyCopyright.tt">
            <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
            <LastGenOutput>AssemblyCopyright.cs</LastGenOutput>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>

For more details ,you could refer to Execute a task from a project file

No, it didn't work-- even in DEBUG configuration, I can still see that the link is included, and the copyright notice generated.. See the updated question

I updated the answer. Hope it helps you find your way. So far, I haven't been successful in testing Target.
